# Como enviar varios parametros AJAX jquery codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo la ruta que pasa dos parametros

```
$route['api/operadores/tabla_operador/(:any)/(:any)']['GET'] = 'api/ApiOperadores/tabla_operador/$1/$2';
```

Tengo la consulta del modelo `public function get_lista_operadores($idtipo_operador, $estado)
{

```
    $this->db_gestion->select('o.idoperador, o.nombre_apellido,o.tipo_operador, t.descripcion as tipo_operador, o.estado , o.id_usuario');
    $this->db_gestion->from('operadores o');
    $this->db_gestion->join('tipo_operador t',"t.idtipo_operador = o.tipo_operador ");

    $this->db_gestion->where("o.tipo_operador" , $idtipo_operador);
   $this->db_gestion->where("o.estado" , $estado);
    $query = $this->db_gestion->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}`
```

Tengo el controlador `ublic function tabla_operador_get($idtipo_operador,$estado)
{
$operador = $this->operadores->get_lista_operadores($idtipo_operador, $estado);

```
    $this->response($operador);

   
}
```

tengo el ajax

```
function tablaOperadores(idtipo_operador, estado){


        $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "api/operadores/tabla_operador/"  + idtipo_operador + "/" + estado ,
                
                    success: function(response)
                        {
                        
                            let thead = '<thead><tr class="info"><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Id</th><th style="width: 50%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Nombre</th><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Tipo</th><th style="width: 10%; padding: 0px; padding-left: 10px;">Estado</th><th style="width: 20%; padding: 0px;">&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>';
                        
                            response.forEach (elemento => {

                                            

                                thead += '<tr>'+
                            '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.idoperador + '</td>'+
                            '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.nombre_apellido + '</td>' +
                            '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle;">' + elemento.tipo_operador + '</td>' +
                            '<td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 20px; vertical-align: middle;">' + (elemento.estado == 0 ? 'Inactivo' : 'Activo') + '</td>' +
                            '<td style="height: 5px; padding: 4px;" align="center">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-xs bg-navy " style="margin:2px" id="ver" title="Ver Datos del Operador" onclick="cargarOperador ( ' +  elemento.idoperador + ', `edit` ,' + elemento.id_usuario + ' );"><i class= "fa fa-eye "></i></a>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="margin:2px" id="editar" title="Actualizar Datos del operador" onclick="cargarOperador( ' +  elemento.idoperador + ', `this` ,' + elemento.id_usuario + ' );"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o "></i></a>'+
                            '<a class="btn btn-xs bg-yellow" style="margin:2px" title="Cambiar Estado" onclick="cambiarEstado(' +  elemento.idoperador + ',' + elemento.estado + ');"><i class="fa fa-exchange " ></i></a>'+
                            '</td>' +'</tr>';       
                        });
                                
                                 
                                $('#listaOperadores').html(thead);
                                $('#listaOperadores').DataTable();
                            
                                                                            
         

                    }
            });  }
```

y el html con los select }

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="slc_tipoOperador" name="slc_tipoOperador"  onchange="tablaOperadores($(this).val())"  onclick="tablaOperadores($('#listaOperadores').DataTable().destroy())" >
            <script>

                var id_operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();
                var idtipo_Operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();
                var idtipo_Operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador')
                listaTipoOperador(id_operador);
                tablaOperadores(idtipo_operador);
                
            </script>                           
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="slc_estado" name="slc_estado" onclick="tablaOperadores($('#listaOperadores').DataTable().destroy())"  onchange="tablaOperadores($(this).val())">
    
            <option value="1">Activo</option>
            <option value="3">Inactivo</option>
            <script>
        
            
            </script>
        </select>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que sucede es que en el segundo select envia el parametro 1 y 0, filtrando la query como el primer select y no por $estado . Pienso que me debe estar faltando definir las variables?

Answer (score 0):

Pude! faltaba declarar parametros en  la funcion antes del ajax

```
function tablaOperadores(idtipo_operador, estado){

        var idtipo_Operador = $('#slc_tipoOperador').val();
        var estado = $('#slc_estado').val();
    

        $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "api/operadores/tabla_operador/"  + idtipo_operador + "/" + estado ,
```